# What happens when I "offline" a disk and is there a difference between diskpart.exe and the disk management snap-in?

Tags: windows, diskmanagement

- What actions does Windows take when I "Offline" a disk in the Disk Management GUI?
- What actions does Windows take when I "Offline" a disk in Diskpart?
- Are there any differences between the two scenarios?

Comment: Taking a disk offline in diskpart is the same as taking it offline in the management GUI.  You may see different behavior based on the GUI having an open "session" to the offlined-disk that errors out, which is not a problem you'll encounter using disk part, or the PowerShell v4 cmdlets.

Answer (score 0):

They work the same. One thing to note is sometimes the two can get out of sync. 
In that case you'll need to restart the logical disk management service and restart at least the GUI.

(I *feel* that the cli version is less likely to trip in that situation, but it's also been a while since I last managed to sufficiently break things.)

Comment: Do you know what processes occur in either case? ACL changes, a bit flipped in the kernel, etc?